# Draw a polygon using designer

Tags: c#, draw, polygon

Is it possible to draw a polygon   on the form using the form designer instead of script?

I need to draw 3 arrow like polygon to indicate the different steps that the code will progress thro. i will indicate the current step using a specific color for the specific polygon. How can i do this?

This needs to be accomplished in a c# winFOrms GUI

Comment: add this comment to your question, please.

Comment: Question is too broad. Show us what your current code is and where you are gettings errors / having problems. We do not write code for you.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: In WinForms the answer is NO, unless you use some third party component - your own, free or paid

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) && [SO Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Comment: I have just created a form with a listbox. Now i need to create 3 polygons (say rhombos) over the list box.I am using WINFORMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neither the winforms nor the WPF Visual Studio designer have this feature.

If you really need a visual designer instead of coding it, you can use the visual designer capabilities of [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/).

However be aware that this tool produces XAML and is only suitable for XAML based technologies such as WPF, WinRT XAML, Silverlight, and Windows Phone.

winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and is not really intended for "drawing" stuff, only for regular ugly Windows 3.1-like UIs.

Comment: "neither the winforms nor the WPF Visual Studio designer have this feature." -> you can modify the XAML by hand and then you see the result even in Visual Studio designer

Comment: @rudolf_franek Right, but the OP is asking to actually "draw" polygons in a Visual Designer, which is a Feature that Visual Studio does not have. Only Blend has a polygon drawing feature that generates `Path`s